# How to check whether the linux system using a large disk space?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, mount

I am using VirtualBox. I installed a ubuntu system on it. At the beginning, I set default 8GB disk space. But it's not big enough so I want to add more space on it.

I used this way(add to 20GB):

```
VBoxManage modifyhd my_ubuntu.vdi --resize 20000
```

After I restart my ubuntu, I run these commands in the terminal:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.3G     0  1.3G   0% /dev
tmpfs           256M  4.4M  251M   2% /run
/dev/sda1       5.3G  5.0G     0 100% /
tmpfs           1.3G  224K  1.3G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.3G     0  1.3G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           256M   48K  256M   1% /run/user/1000

$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 19.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0  5.5G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0    1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0  2.6G  0 part [SWAP]
sr0     11:0    1 55.5M  0 rom
```

Why can't I see the addition space under `df -h` command? But can see it by using `lsblk`? And, is it really that my system is 20GB available and useful now?

Comment: You made the (virtual) device bigger. The partitions are intact. Now rearrange your partitions within `sda`, expand `sda1`, then expand the filesystem within `sda1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You extended the size of the disk, but you will also need to grow your partition and the filesystem within that parition.  Unfortunately your filesystem is on the partition at the beginning of your disk which makes things more complicated.  If you were using LVM you would be able to reallocate the space as needed, but since you're using disk paritions it will be a little more involved.

You could try using [PartedMagic](https://partedmagic.com) to resize your partitions and filesystems.  Alternatively you can boot off the Ubuntu install disk and run gparted to get the same functionality.  As long as your filesystems are supported by the tool it should be able to resize them for you.